# Wordpress slider, not displayed 100% width

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

So im making my first Wordpress theme from scratch everything is going fine but now i got a problem. I want a Slider on the homepage but one thing is wrong. Im setting the width of the image to 100% !important but it doesnt go 100% width. It makes the image wider but not 100%.

Example is here: http://bit.ly/11OuEBg
You see the image doesnt contain the whole width. But you can see the background-color.

Really weird, im using Meteor slides.

I hope someone can help me out :D

Comment: As far as I can see, a width of 940px is getting applied to the image from JavaScript. Check it and try to change it to 100%. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's because the img's parents (div elements) have fixed width in css

Comment: But how is that possible, i want to overwrite it. So i used width: 100% !important on the image. Why isnt that working?